# Core Data lightweight migration taking long & crashing

Tags: macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings, core-data-migration

I have an OS X app that uses Core Data & Bindings and was recently updated to a new version. The newer version contains an updated data model (which consists of one additional entity that doesn’t have any relationships to the previous ones). The updates to the data model are inside two versions and I use the automatic lightweight migration feature. Both versions get shipped inside the app. We have thousands of users who already updated. We didn’t get any support requests nor automatic crash reports because of this issue. That’s the reason why I assume that my code is (kind of) OK-ish.

But there’s still this one stack trace that makes me crazy:

```
OS Version:      10.9.2 (Build 13C1021)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  18

Command:         Rainbow Unicorn
Path:            /Applications/Rainbow Unicorn.app/Contents/MacOS/Rainbow Unicorn
Version:         1.8 (35)
App Item ID:     414704443
App External ID: 510002694
Parent:          launchd [155]

PID:             1390
Event:           hang
Duration:        4.84s (process was unresponsive for 117 seconds before sampling)
Steps:           40 (100ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro8,1
Active cpus:     4
Fan speed:       1996 rpm

Free pages:      31445 pages (-25644)
Pageins:         144 pages
Pageouts:        0 pages
Swapins:         0 pages
Swapouts:        0 pages


Process:         Rainbow Unicorn [1390]
Path:            /Applications/Rainbow Unicorn.app/Contents/MacOS/Rainbow Unicorn
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          launchd [155]
UID:             501
Task size:       77873 pages (+13047)
CPU Time:        0.227s
Note:            Unresponsive for 117 seconds before sampling

  Thread 0xd10a6    DispatchQueue 1          priority 46         cpu time   0.227s
  40 start + 1 (libdyld.dylib) [0x7fff835ed5fd]
    40 NSApplicationMain + 448 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b328727]
      40 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 357 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b32c8db]
        40 -[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:] + 197 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b32caec]
          40 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 288 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b32ccfc]
            40 loadNib + 327 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b32d75e]
              40 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 1004 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b338bf4]
                40 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueBindingCreation) bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:] + 652 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b3d30a8]
                  40 -[NSObjectParameterBinder _updateObject:observedController:observedKeyPath:context:] + 1118 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b3dbff9]
                    40 -[NSBinder valueForBinding:resolveMarkersToPlaceholders:] + 160 (AppKit) [0x7fff8b3dc3bd]
                      40 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 334 (Foundation) [0x7fff890714ff]
                        40 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 381 (Foundation) [0x7fff89059466]
                          40 ??? (Rainbow Unicorn + 13382) [0x10871c446]
                            40 ??? (Rainbow Unicorn + 12213) [0x10871bfb5]
                              40 ??? (Rainbow Unicorn + 12919) [0x10871c277]
                                40 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:] + 4014 (CoreData) [0x7fff888bb4de]
                                  40 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:] + 2039 (CoreData) [0x7fff889c60a7]
                                    40 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy migrateStoreAtURL:withManager:metadata:options:error:] + 102 (CoreData) [0x7fff889c4626]
                                      40 -[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) migrateStoreAtURL:toURL:storeType:options:withManager:error:] + 290 (CoreData) [0x7fff889c5792]
                                        40 -[NSMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 521 (CoreData) [0x7fff889c7889]
                                          40 -[NSSQLiteInPlaceMigrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:type:options:withMappingModel:toDestinationURL:destinationType:destinationOptions:error:] + 1737 (CoreData) [0x7fff889ddac9]
                                            40 -[_NSSQLiteStoreMigrator performMigration:] + 782 (CoreData) [0x7fff889e142e]
                                              40 -[NSSQLConnection prepareAndExecuteSQLStatement:] + 52 (CoreData) [0x7fff88901e44]
                                                40 -[NSSQLiteConnection execute] + 2040 (CoreData) [0x7fff888c75d8]
                                                  40 _execute + 214 (CoreData) [0x7fff888c7926]
                                                    40 sqlite3_step + 666 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893be40a]
                                                      32 sqlite3VdbeExec + 68340 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893cff44]
                                                        32 sqlite3VdbeMemFromBtree + 438 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893db306]
                                                          29 accessPayload + 752 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893fa6c0]
                                                            29 sqlite3PagerAcquire + 349 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a518d]
                                                              29 readDbPage + 478 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a65ee]
                                                                29 pread + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff835a4962]
                                                                 *29 hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f3b76]
                                                                   *29 unix_syscall64 + 499 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800063e413]
                                                                     *29 pread_nocancel + 137 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005efc49]
                                                                       *29 ??? (mach_kernel + 4127438) [0xffffff80005eface]
                                                                         *29 ??? (mach_kernel + 2045365) [0xffffff80003f35b5]
                                                                           *29 VNOP_READ + 225 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003fda01]
                                                                             *29 hfs_vnop_read + 566 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800056b1f6]
                                                                               *29 cluster_read_ext + 5045 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003d0765]
                                                                                 *28 ??? (mach_kernel + 1904306) [0xffffff80003d0eb2]
                                                                                   *28 ??? (mach_kernel + 1910723) [0xffffff80003d27c3]
                                                                                     *28 memory_object_control_uiomove + 284 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800026cdcc]
                                                                                       *28 lck_rw_sleep + 81 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800022d921]
                                                                                         *28 thread_block_reason + 204 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000235d8c]
                                                                                           *28 ??? (mach_kernel + 223627) [0xffffff800023698b]
                                                                                             *28 machine_switch_context + 354 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d7e92]
                                                                                 *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 1904418) [0xffffff80003d0f22]
                                                                                   *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 1914137) [0xffffff80003d3519]
                                                                                     *1  lck_rw_lock_exclusive + 17 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d0c81]
                                                          3  accessPayload + 918 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893fa766]
                                                            3  _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 178 (libsystem_platform.dylib) [0x7fff8b19c092]
                                                             *3  hndl_alltraps + 219 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f327b]
                                                               *3  user_trap + 748 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002dc2bc]
                                                                 *2  vm_fault + 5246 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002791be]
                                                                   *2  delay + 51 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002221d3]
                                                                     *2  thread_block_reason + 204 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000235d8c]
                                                                       *2  ??? (mach_kernel + 223627) [0xffffff800023698b]
                                                                         *2  machine_switch_context + 354 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d7e92]
                                                                 *1  vm_fault + 4767 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000278fdf]
                                                                   *1  vm_fault_enter + 2631 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000277587]
                                                                     *1  pmap_enter_options + 5013 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002c4ef5]
                                                      7  sqlite3VdbeExec + 30051 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893c69b3]
                                                        7  sqlite3BtreeInsert + 1205 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893e6655]
                                                          6  allocateBtreePage + 1626 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893ecbba]
                                                            5  sqlite3PagerAcquire + 349 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a518d]
                                                              5  readDbPage + 478 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a65ee]
                                                                5  pread + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff835a4962]
                                                                 *5  hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f3b76]
                                                                   *5  unix_syscall64 + 499 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800063e413]
                                                                     *5  pread_nocancel + 137 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005efc49]
                                                                       *5  ??? (mach_kernel + 4127438) [0xffffff80005eface]
                                                                         *5  ??? (mach_kernel + 2045365) [0xffffff80003f35b5]
                                                                           *5  VNOP_READ + 225 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003fda01]
                                                                             *5  hfs_vnop_read + 566 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800056b1f6]
                                                                               *5  cluster_read_ext + 5045 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003d0765]
                                                                                 *5  ??? (mach_kernel + 1905981) [0xffffff80003d153d]
                                                                                   *5  msleep + 114 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005e1852]
                                                                                     *5  ??? (mach_kernel + 4068901) [0xffffff80005e1625]
                                                                                       *5  lck_mtx_sleep + 78 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800022d1be]
                                                                                         *5  thread_block_reason + 204 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000235d8c]
                                                                                           *5  ??? (mach_kernel + 223627) [0xffffff800023698b]
                                                                                             *5  machine_switch_context + 354 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d7e92]
                                                            1  sqlite3PagerAcquire + 68 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a5074]
                                                              1  sqlite3PcacheFetch + 299 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a53fb]
                                                                1  pagerStress + 326 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff8943b736]
                                                                  1  syncJournal + 436 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893efec4]
                                                                    1  fsync + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff835a4392]
                                                                     *1  hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f3b76]
                                                                       *1  unix_syscall64 + 499 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800063e413]
                                                                         *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 2010599) [0xffffff80003eade7]
                                                                           *1  VNOP_FSYNC + 67 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003fe063]
                                                                             *1  hfs_vnop_fsync + 107 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000589fbb]
                                                                               *1  hfs_fsync + 295 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000586677]
                                                                                 *1  cluster_push_ext + 521 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003d1e39]
                                                                                   *1  vnode_waitforwrites + 227 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003d8693]
                                                                                     *1  msleep + 114 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005e1852]
                                                                                       *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 4068901) [0xffffff80005e1625]
                                                                                         *1  lck_mtx_sleep + 78 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800022d1be]
                                                                                           *1  thread_block_reason + 204 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000235d8c]
                                                                                             *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 223627) [0xffffff800023698b]
                                                                                               *1  machine_switch_context + 354 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d7e92]
                                                          1  allocateBtreePage + 1691 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893ecbfb]
                                                            1  sqlite3PagerWrite + 90 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893e330a]
                                                              1  pager_write + 1450 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893e3e7a]
                                                                1  pwrite + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff835a49aa]
                                                                 *1  hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f3b76]
                                                                   *1  unix_syscall64 + 499 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800063e413]
                                                                     *1  pwrite_nocancel + 362 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005f030a]
                                                                       *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 4128961) [0xffffff80005f00c1]
                                                                         *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 2046147) [0xffffff80003f38c3]
                                                                           *1  VNOP_WRITE + 225 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003fdb31]
                                                                             *1  hfs_vnop_write + 2472 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800056bce8]
                                                                               *1  cluster_write + 37 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003cd0a5]
                                                                                 *1  cluster_write_ext + 3864 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003cdfc8]
                                                                                   *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 1896259) [0xffffff80003cef43]
                                                                                     *1  ubc_upl_commit_range + 136 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000600138]
                                                                                       *1  upl_commit_range + 3006 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800029dd6e]
                                                      1  sqlite3VdbeExec + 4284 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893c050c]
                                                        1  sqlite3BtreeMovetoUnpacked + 1143 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893da8f7]
                                                          1  sqlite3PagerAcquire + 349 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a518d]
                                                            1  readDbPage + 478 (libsqlite3.dylib) [0x7fff893a65ee]
                                                              1  pread + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib) [0x7fff835a4962]
                                                               *1  hndl_unix_scall64 + 22 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002f3b76]
                                                                 *1  unix_syscall64 + 499 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800063e413]
                                                                   *1  pread_nocancel + 137 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005efc49]
                                                                     *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 4127438) [0xffffff80005eface]
                                                                       *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 2045365) [0xffffff80003f35b5]
                                                                         *1  VNOP_READ + 225 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003fda01]
                                                                           *1  hfs_vnop_read + 566 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800056b1f6]
                                                                             *1  cluster_read_ext + 5045 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80003d0765]
                                                                               *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 1905981) [0xffffff80003d153d]
                                                                                 *1  msleep + 114 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80005e1852]
                                                                                   *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 4068901) [0xffffff80005e1625]
                                                                                     *1  lck_mtx_sleep + 78 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff800022d1be]
                                                                                       *1  thread_block_reason + 204 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff8000235d8c]
                                                                                         *1  ??? (mach_kernel + 223627) [0xffffff800023698b]
                                                                                           *1  machine_switch_context + 354 (mach_kernel) [0xffffff80002d7e92]
```

It only happens for one customer and it’s reproducible on her Mac. Do you have an idea what the source of the issue is? How can I fix this bug? The only things I know so far are that the crash happens during the automatic lightweight migration and that it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Are *you* using multiple threads?  Or is that core data causing the sql threading...

Comment: I don’t use multiple threads with Core Data. It looks like it would come from the SQLite library.